# How would I go about implementing a loop in this script?

Tags: python, loops

How do I loop this code until it detects discord isn't running anymore and prints out the else line?

```
import psutil

def checkIfProcessRunning(processName):

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:           
        if processName.lower() in proc.name().lower():
            return True
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass
return False;

if checkIfProcessRunning('discord'):
  print('Discord is running')
else:
  print('Discord is NOT running')
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to say here: you seem to know about loops, yet somehow don't know how to use one... Learn how loops work, I guess? Cuz the answer is literally a matter of one or two lines of code and proper indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an infinite loop that has a break condition. So at the end of your code you would have something like:

```
while checkIfProcessRunning('discord'):
    print('Discord is running')
print('Discord is NOT running')
```

This will work by continually calling `checkIfProcessRunning('discord')`. If it returns `True`, then it continues in the loop and checks again. When you returns `False`, then the loop will break.

However, this will be printing a lot of `Discord is running`, so you might want to have some type of sleep method in that loop to only check every 5 seconds or some amount of time like this:

```
from time import sleep

while checkIfProcessRunning('discord'):
    print('Discord is running')
    sleep(5)
print('Discord is NOT running')
```